# Testing a function that combines Observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have been tasked with testing observables and I am fairly new to the concept. I have a fair idea of how Observables work, and I need to test a function `andCombine` that takes two observables and returns the AND result.

```
  it('tests andCombine', () => {
       const coldOne = cold('t----f|', {t : true, f : false});
       const coldTwo = cold('t-f|', {t : true, f : false});
       const result = cold('t-f--f|', {t : true, f : false});
       const combined = andCombine(coldOne, coldTwo);
       expect(combined).toBeObservable(result);

    });
```

The andCombine looks like

```
export const andCombine = (...source$: Observable<any>[]): Observable<any> => {
    return combineLatest(source$.filter(data => !!data)).pipe(
        map(([...args]: [any[]]) => {
            return args.reduce((acc, arg) => {
                return acc && !!arg;
            }, true);
        }),
        distinctUntilChanged()
    );
};
```

And I have the following error logs.

```
   Error: Expected $.length = 3 to equal 4.
        Expected $[2].frame = 60 to equal 50.
        Expected $[2].notification.kind = 'C' to equal 'N'.
        Expected $[2].notification.value = undefined to equal false.
        Expected $[2].notification.hasValue = false to equal true.
        Expected $[3] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 60, notification: Notification({ kind: 'C', value: undefined, error: undefined, hasValue: false }) }).
```

I know there is something very basic that is missing and I would like someone to help me understand how this thing works and where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `distinctUntilChanged()`, therefore the second `false` notification will be ignored.

#### DistinctUntilChanged

> Returns an Observable that emits all items emitted by the source Observable that are distinct by comparison from the previous item.

i.e. `false`, `false`, `false` from the source leads to just one `false` for the output observable.

I suppose your test is correct if you test for:

```
const result = cold('t-f---|', {t : true, f : false});
```

... or remove the `distinctUntilChanged`, depending on your use case.

[Further reading](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged)